# Webshop to buy vegetarian/vegan products online delivering in Canada?

Tags: vegetarian, vegan, websites

I would love shops with bulk of almonds, various beans (soy,lentils,chickpeas), speciality cereals like quinoa/amaranth, seitan mix, vegan fake chiken, broths, wheat grass, vegetarian/vegan fake meats ...

As I buy from Quebec, it could be harder a little ...

Answer (score 1):

[Go Dairy Free's list of online food retailers](http://www.godairyfree.org/Food-to-Eat/Online-Food-Retailers/) is a good start.

Have a google of Indian/Asian/Baking supplies too. Doesn't have to be an all Vegan online source, eh?

I relied on a middle-eastern import company for pulses years ago before they were available locally. Had to order 10K sacks! Learned to share the bargain with friends.

Comment: I'm flexitarian so Vegetarian/Vegan sites aren't needed, but they have mostly the speciality products that I want ...

Answer (score 1):

My wife and I have purchased from [The Vegan Store](http://www.veganstore.com/) many times and been happy with their product selection.  They don't carry fresh produce, but they have all manner of dry and refrigerated packaged goods, as well as pet supplies, books, clothing and more.

Their [shipping page](http://www.veganstore.com/shipping) indicates that they do ship to Canada.  If you plan on buying anything that needs refrigeration, you should not that you may need to include a cold pack with your order, which can be expensive.

Comment: Really nice shop, I checked it ... ;)

It handles exactly what I needed, I found it via another response ...

Answer (score -3):

You're *not* going to have much luck with "online" organic food in Canada.  I'll talk about it later, but first I'll talk about shopping yourself.

[Bulk Barn](http://www.bulkbarn.ca/) actually has a ton of organic grains (eg [ORGANIC QUINOA](http://www.bulkbarn.ca/en-ca/products.html?product=3273&search=organic)).

Other stores (highly hit and miss) that carry organics are:  Sobey's, Loblaws, Costco, and The Real Canadian Superstore.

Just show up and browse the produce.  Sometimes you'll find a killer deal on organic grapefruit at one of them, and completely zero organic stock in the other.

Costco carries [Earthbound organics](http://www.ebfarm.com/) salads (large boxes) in their fridge section.  The price or less is the same as conventional salad in a regular grocery store.

If you're in Toronto, try also [Ambrosia](http://www.ambrosianaturalfoods.com/).

## On Online delivery

I don't have a good experience with online food delivery.  I just don't see a need to pay to get it delivered, when I can easily go out and get it myself.  You don't get to choose the fruits you get, and *you are going to pay much more*.

That said, there's a listing [here](http://veg.ca/directory/list/organic-delivery), and it includes a group called [Front Door Organics](http://www.frontdoororganics.com/).

Now I haven't tried them, but browsing their produce, it looks promising.  Still,
you're probably not going to have much luck with *online* services that do delivery, simply because it's too expensive and you don't get much bang for your buck, plus you can't pick the fruits that are in good condition.  You're better off going to the store yourself.

Comment: I was seeking for non-perissables products mostly, fruits/vegetables aren't needed as I help a community garden project and get a pretty decent share ...

Comment: I'm confused: the OP is asking for ingredients commonly used in vegetarian/vegan cooking (though some aren't really vegetarian/vegan-specific), not organic food, and never even mentioned produce.

Comment: beans, grains, nuts, fake meats (for veg. meals), veg. broths, wheat/oat grass for green juices ...

It's all vegetarian/vegan produces that I want cause they don't have much here and when I travel to my home town it's even far worse, they just have tofu, soy milk and hummus, the prices are 2-3 times higher then where, like if it wasn't enough ...

Even if it would be a little higher priced than a regular shop, I wouldn't go for nothing and save gaz, I go check regulars shops each week cause the flyers specials doesn't included the veg. products ...